# customize Zefyr flutter package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm using the [Zefyr](https://pub.dev/packages/zefyr) package for text editing. It has a property of toolbar Delegate can't customize it. Can somebody help?

```
class AddArticleScreen extends StatelessWidget {
final AddArticleController addArticleController =
  Get.put(AddArticleController());
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: ZefyrScaffold(
          child: ZefyrEditor(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        controller: addArticleController.zefyrController,
        focusNode: addArticleController.focusNode,
        toolbarDelegate: ,
      )),
    ),
  ),
    );
   }
}
```